# Configurations Attribute not working.

Tags: magento2

I have a bunch of attributes I would like to make configurations based on ( like weight, as well as voltage and etc.). I have created Attributes in Store--> Products and also have assigned those Attributes to Store-->Attribute Sets.

Now I also need to have those options in my configuration panel. How am I able to do it?

Comment: Is the issue that you want the attributes to display in the list of attributes when creating configurable options with a new configurable product?

Comment: Yes, I have created the attributes, but they will not be shown under configuratable products.

Comment: I've answered the question - let me know if that helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display an attribute in the configurable options form, it must have the following properties set:

- The `frontend_input` type must be set to select
- The attribute must be set as user-defined, and it sounds like yours are,
- and the scope of the attribute (Stores -> product -> view your attribute -> Advanced attribute properties) must be set to global.

Please let me know if this helps, or if you have any other questions!

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped.